# How to fix json_decode out put

Tags: php

when in use json_decod with option "JSON_FORCE_OBJECT" its return out put index started with 0 and its true but i need to start the out put index with 1 so how i can fix my problem?

```
json_encode($request->get('poll_items'), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

The output result is and current BUT:

```
"{"0":"option1","1":"option2","2":"option3"}"
```

I need to return like this:

```
"{"1":"option1","2":"option2","3":"option3"}"
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing the results of the method call is an indexed array? Why do you need to convert an indexed array to an object? Can you give us some context?

Comment: Can you share the original structure of your array? Maybe the values start with index 0, as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to use `array_unshift()` and `unset()`:

```
$array = $request->get('poll_items');

// Add an element to the beginning
array_shift($array, '');

// Unset the first element
unset($array[0]);
```

Now you're left with an associative array that starts with `1`.

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/SBgg7)

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be why do you need this to be 1 indexed instead of 0?

If this data is consumed outside of your control then you could map the data across to another array and encode that instead. For example:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($request->get('poll_items') as $index => $value) {
    $newArray[++$index] = $value
}
$output = json_encode($newArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

NOTE: `++$index` instead of `$index++` as the latter will only alter the value after the line has computed.